# Scrape dynamically loaded website

Tags: python, curl, web-scraping, scrapy

When I load the page "http://proxydb.net" using cURL, or try to scrape the page, then the response body is empty. Apparently, the page is dynamically loaded using JavaScript.

What would be options to still load the rendered source code?

I tried using Selenium using the Firefox driver, but this pushes my CPU-usage to 100 percent in only 15 seconds. I guess that this is not a viable option, especially not for larger projects that involve scraping 100,000+ pages using Selenium.

Furthermore, to understand the concept of dynamically loaded pages. How do these work? What code is required to make them work?

Comment: Try using python with scrapy-splash for dynamically loading pages

Comment: can you try using https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup, I've personally not attempted it but it might help. If this doesnt work then you might have to go the selenium way.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try it. Is there a way to keep the webbrowser open when using Selenium? In my case, the browser is opened and then closed for each request, which highly consumes my system resources.

Answer (score 0):

`When I load the page "http://proxydb.net" using cURL, or try to scrape the page, then the response body is empty` - because this particular website use a user-agent whitelist, and if your user-agent is not on the whitelist, you just get served a blank page. presumably, all major web browsers are whitelisted (Chrome, Internet Explorer, Edge, Safari, Opera, etc), but here's a specific user-agent that is whitelisted:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

(the user-agent of Chrome 65 running on windows 7 x64), and thus, this works:

```
curl 'http://proxydb.net/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
```

as for how to load content dynamically, that's usually done with [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), or in older code, iframes.

`Apparently, the page is dynamically loaded using JavaScript.` - wrong, these guys are not loading the proxy list dynamically, they're embedded directly into the front page (as long as you're using a whitelisted user-agent), obscured as

```
var q = '42.86.831'.split('').reverse().join('');
var yy = /* */ atob('\x4d\x43\x34\x79\x4d\x54\x67\x3d'.replace(/\\x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/g, function() {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(arguments[1], 16))
}));
var pp = (3109 - ([] + [])) /**/ + (+document.querySelector('[data-numr]').getAttribute('data-numr')) - [] + [];
document.write('<a href="/' + q + yy + '/' + pp + '#http">' + q + yy + String.fromCharCode(58) + pp + '</a>');
```

(which, together with the data-numr div in this case ,translates to `138.68.240.218:3128` - and it's actually encrypted, and the decryption key is in a div looking like `<div style="display:none" data-numr="19"></div>`, here the key was 19.)